# Why does *(&identifier)=value works in C?

Tags: c, dereference

For example,

```
int x = 10;
*(&x) = 20;
printf("%d \n",x); // output is 20
```

According to ISO C11-6.5.3.2 paragraph 4, it says that

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand
>   has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undefined.

Since the operand `&x` is neither function designator nor object designator (it is a pointer to type int), I expected undefined behaviour but it works just fine! What am I missing?

Comment: "If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’", the operand clearly has pointer to type.

Comment: why would you think the value `&x` is an invalid value?

Comment: "*if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object.*" `&x` points to `int`, namely `x`.

Comment: The operand (`&x`) points to an object and has a type of `pointer to int`, therefore the result is an lvalue designating an object of type int, exactly as the paragraph says.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to learn C by reading the standard ? If so, I'd recommend you find some other resource. The standard is aimed towards compiler writers who already understand the language pretty well, not beginners.

Comment: @Jin How about the part where it says "the result is an **lvalue** designating the object"?

Comment: @Quentin I just wanted to know what the standard says about that operator. That's all! By the way, I'm learning C by C Primer Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me parse it for you:

```
int x = 10;
*(&x) = 20;
```

- `*` == the asterisk operator
- `&x` == the operand (of the asterisk operator)

> If the operand points to a function, the result is a function
>   designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue
>   designating the object.

The operand (&x == address of x where x is an int) points to an object of type int.

=> The result is an lvalue designating x (x==the object).

> If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type
>   ‘‘type’’.

The operand has type *pointer to int*, therefore the result has type int.

Answer (score 5):

The operator `&x` indicates the address of variable `x`. When you use an asterisk in front of it, this indicates the ***content at the address of variable `x`***, which is simply `x`.

The operators `*` and `&` neutralize each other, when used like that.